# DIfference between officeppe.com and office.live.com?

Tags: office365, office365-apps, ms-wopi

I have to integrate document management Web application to office 365 for editing docs online, Now I have one problem in case of business user , wopi client is redirecting to officeppe.com & when I add credentials (e.g xyz@zyz.onmicrosoft.com) it gives me user is not in system. So what I did I replaced officeppe.com by office.live.com and then I have provided same credentials and it worked. So want o know why this happened ? What is difference between officeppe.com and office.live.com

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about programming

Answer (score 3):

This is because [officeppe.com](https://officeppe.com) is a staging website used for internal development so this means that production [office.com](https://officeppe.com) credentials will not work on it.